# How to get rid of an unwanted space in a tab menu?

Tags: html, css

I am using asp.net mvc and I am working on a tab menu which is displaying an unwanted space between each tab. This only happens when I have each image tag on its own line as opposed to having it all in one.

[image]

The top images are on their own line which is what is causing the unwanted space:

```
        <img src="/Content/Images/Reports_white.png"/>
        <img src="/Content/Images/Audit_white.png"/>
        <img src="/Content/Images/Messages_white.png"/>
        <img src="/Content/Images/Admin_white.png"/>
```

versus the desired effect on the bottom half of the image:

```
        <img src="/Content/Images/Reports_white.png"/><img src="/Content/Images/Audit_white.png"/> ...
```

How can I get rid of this space without having to keep them all on one line?

Comment: Cleaned up your tags and added the image for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd contain your tab images in an unordered list like this:

CSS:

```
ul.tabs
{
list-style:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

ul.tabs li
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><img src="/Content/Images/Reports_white.png"/></li>
<li><img src="/Content/Images/Audit_white.png"/></li>
<li><img src="/Content/Images/Messages_white.png"/></li>
<li><img src="/Content/Images/Admin_white.png"/></li>
</ul>
```

That way you can control the spacing using padding or margin.

Answer (score 1):

one technique is to do

```
    <img src="/Content/Images/Reports_white.png"
    /><img src="/Content/Images/Audit_white.png"
    /><img src="/Content/Images/Messages_white.png"
    /><img src="/Content/Images/Admin_white.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you will probably want the tabs to be clickable you will need to add some elements `DIV` for example around the images. Make sure those elements have no margins and you can have whitespace inbetween the divs in the source no problem.

```
    <div><img src="/Content/Images/Reports_white.png"/></div>
    <div><img src="/Content/Images/Audit_white.png"/></div>
    <div><img src="/Content/Images/Messages_white.png"/></div>
    <div><img src="/Content/Images/Admin_white.png"/></div>
```

Comment: why would the images not be clickable? a div tag is not an anchor... if using javascript events, the image tag can raise those events just as well as a div.

Comment: I used the div as an example. Charlie's answer is more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Any space between tags, e.g. a new line, are interpreted as white space. This only really affects inline elements, which <img> elements are so hence your problem.

You could also try adding `float: left` to the elements which will stack them horizontally without any spacing. Presumably you're actually implementing these as hyperlinks, we'd have to see the exact markup to suggest a specific solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Remove the spaces between the `img` tags and make sure they have no margins.

If you don't want to bother about having spaces in the HTML, take some time to make them `float:left`, contained in a `div` (`overflow:hidden` will get its height correct).